# Absence du verbe "emphasiser"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes, linguistique

Le mot *emphase* existe en français avec deux significations (selon [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/emphase/28913)) l'une étant *mise en relief*. Je me demande donc pourquoi le verbe *emphasiser* n'existe pas en français.

Nota bene : Je sais bien sûr qu'il est d'autres verbes et expressions avec mettre qui rendent en français le même sens.

Comment: Euh, « interprètent le même sens » ? Tu utilises trop souvent le verbe *interpréter* et pas de la bonne façon. *Interpréter* signifie « donner du sens », « rendre accessible », « produire / donner vie » au sens de produire, par exemple un morceau de musique, ou une pièce de théâtre. Il y a en général plusieurs façons d'interpréter. Une autre façon de voir ça c'est « concevoir à partir d'un original ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je t'ai remercie ; je l'ai corrigé. Merci !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il ne faut pas dire trop vite qu'il n'existe pas ; le point de vue inconscient que parce qu'une forme existe en anglais il faille automatiquement la trouver en français n'a pas de fondement ; vu les origines de ces deux langages il y a une certaine tendance pour que cela arrive mais aucune règle, aucun principe vraiment sûr ; on s'aperçoit que des formes terminées en « -ent » par exemple sont parfois les mêmes dans les deux langues (parent, pigment, talent,…) mais c'est souvent une question de pile ou face quant à l'existence de la forme dans les deux langues **et** d'une même signification (figment, lenient, garment, dent, rodent …) ; ce principe est évidemment valide dans l'autre sens, du français à l'anglais ; le pourquoi de l'absence d'une forme est donc le plus souvent « parce que des circonstances dues entièrement au hasard, fondées sur aucun principe d'évolution commune des deux langues n'ont pas faites les choses ainsi ».
Le verbe « to emphasise » n'a pas la même forme en français mais il existe en une assez copieuse variété de nuances ; les termes correspondants suivants sont tirés des dictionnaires *Harrap* et *Collins Robert*:

> insister sur, accentuer, appuyer sur, souligner, mettre en valeur, faire ressortir,

On peut en ajouter d'autres ;

- mettre en évidence (mettre une particularité en évidence), rehausser, donner de l'importance

  exemples
- In order **to emphasise** this detail he pronounced the  words with force.
  De façon **à souligner** ce détail il prononça les mots énergiquement.
- To **emphasise** words in your handwritten reports you should underline them.
  Pour **donner** aux mots **de l'importance** dans vos comptes rendus écrits à la main vous devriez les souligner.
- I'd like **to emphasise** that not all the personnel with benefit from this.
  Je voudrais **insister sur le fait** que ne profitera de cela que seulement une partie du personnel.